# C# BinaryWriter Seek

Tags: c#

i have some error in my code i need any one to help me please :)

i have offset and when i try to patch it with C# i get a strange result

```
this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "Sro_Client.exe";
if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FileStream output = new FileStream(this.openFileDialog1.FileName
                                       , FileMode.Open);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { byte.Parse(this.textBox1.Text) };
    byte[] buffer = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(this.textBox1.Text) };
    writer.Seek(0x135FB3, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, 1);
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully patched Sro_Client.exe.");
}
```

the original offset is PUSH 6E , so my program must change it when i write in textbox1 like 90 convert it to hex like [this](http://www.langeneggers.ch/nuetzliches/umrechner-hex-dez.html) website  and change it to : PUSH 5a

so it must be now : 00135FB3   6A 5A            PUSH 5A
but my program change it to 00135FB3   5A               POP EDX

i need to know what is wrong on my code please

thanks

sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: Obviously your program actually *does* change something at `0x00135FB3`, but it writes the "wrong" data there. It writes the data you insert and that's the actual problem. If you are writing wrong data into your textbox, how could we help you debug your code? We need at least some more information about your inputs (contents of `textBox1`).

Comment: what i write on textbox is 90 and the progrram convert it successfully  to 5A but he doesn't patch it right he must change PUCH VALUES but he change the 6A VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the right offset ? Seems to me like 0x00135FB3 is offset of instruction and 0x00135FB4 is offset of argument; have you tried:

```
writer.Seek(0x135FB4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

in your code instead ?

Comment: yes i have the right offset i'm sure because it's edited successfully i check it with ollydebug but program financed it with a wrong values please give me your skype or add me : king.sro29

Comment: oh i try now your code and it's successfully and now it's working fine ! :D thanks so every time when i have offset like dat i have to +1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert data to a file directly using the C# IO classes. The easiest way would be to either read it into a buffer and manipulate the buffer, or write the first part to a temp file, then insert your new data, and then write the remainder of the file and then rename it. Alternatively you can append some data at the end of the file and move everything up to create the right amount of usable space where you want to insert your data.

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17716/Insert-Text-into-Existing-Files-in-C-Without-Temp